# What is the main purpose of meta.stackoverflow?

Tags: support, meta

I understand all subservices of Stack Overflow, except the Meta one. Do I post requests, faq-like questions or do I just vent my happiness/dissatisfaction with the services?

I noticed, most questions are "feature requests", thus - what is the reasoning behind posting answers?

Maybe an edited version of my question could end up inside the faq?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Visit http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: thank you for the uberfast response, however the faq is long and not clear to me ;(

Comment: Did you read the [Meta-FAQ] and the [Meta FAQ overview post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)?

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai: yet the answers to your question are in there. :-)

Comment: READ FOR ME!!!!

Comment: Some of the people on stackoverflow are such douchebags. Rise above. This is the link you MIGHT find if you were LUCKY and PERSISTENT and had PLENTY OF TIME TO WASTE TRYING TO FIND THE ANSWER TO YOUR PERFECTLY REASONABLE QUESTION: metahomepage > help > http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about

Why do we need this site?

The FAQ on all sites explicitly disallows meta-discussion, to reduce clutter and noise.

> Also, try to refrain from asking questions about this website itself
>   unless you absolutely, positively have to. People don’t come here to
>   learn about the intricacies of this website; they come here to get
>   answers to their questions. Let’s try to help them out by not
>   cluttering up the system with navelgazing meta-discussion. If you want
>   to suggest a feature or discuss how the website works, visit our meta
>   site.

This frustrated many members of the community who had perfectly legitimate reasons to ask questions about how and why the websites worked the way they do. We needed to provide an outlet for this activity, a separate place where community members could go for sanctioned meta-discussion. And here it is!