# What does "Meta" mean?

Tags: support, meta

I am fairly new to Stack Overflow and just stumbled across Meta Stack Overflow.

I can't seem to figure out what the purpose of the "Meta" site is. Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define:meta

Comment: The word itself means "self-referential."  In computing, metadata means data about data.  So Meta Stack Overflow is a site where you can ask questions *about* Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Meta means murder](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/meta-is-murder.html)

Comment: @juergend: From the mouth of the guy who finally relented, allowed this site to happen, and then unequivocally stated that it was the [best decision they ever made](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do.html).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171300/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-meta-stackoverflow

Comment: Not sure if attempt at April Fool or legit!

Comment: Ok - So the question is a duplicate. I tried several different searches and neither of those questions came up. The original question stated that also... until someone edited it and removed that info.

Comment: What search terms did you use?

Comment: This question should be on meta.meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meta is the discussion about the discussion. In this context it is a Stack Exchange for Stack Exchanges, where you can ask questions about Stack Exchanges.

A slightly amusing point that this question could belong in the meta-meta stack exchange. To the tune of "What is the purpose of Meta Stack Exchanges?"

Comment: M E T A C E P T I O N

Comment: Got it - Enjoyed the humour also!

Comment: [Meta is its own Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-about-meta-meta-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 3):

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is for Q&A site about programming, while [Meta.StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) is a Q&A about Stack Overflow.

Technically speaking, it's also a Q&A site about the entire [Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites.](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday)

They started expanding and creating Q&A sites for other topics than just programming, and still haven't gotten around to separating the *"Q&A about Stack Overflow"* content from the *"Q&A about all Stack Exchange sites"* content.